# How to inherit log4j configuration xml?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a `log4j2.xml` that performs basic webservice logging. As I want to include the webservice project as dependency within another project, I'd like to inherit the logging configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="rolling">
            ...
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="rolling />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

As I did not find a way so far to inherit this config. Is it impossible?

Comment: Do you want to inherit from the new project (i.e. the one which depends on the webservice) or do you want to import the webservice's config into the new project?

Comment: I want to import the existing webservice config into the new project, as I anyhow import the existing webservice dependency to use it inside the new project.

Comment: That's not an answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you mean by inheriting a logging configuration, but log4j2 [supports XInclude](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-341) for XML configurations. I hope that is useful.